# Promethues check external API json response

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

We are using the [kube-prom-stack](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack) installed in our cluster and we need now to check an endpoint (outside the cluster) . the endpoint return the response in JSON format and we need to take s**ome property from this JSON response** and decide to fire an alert or not, I found the `black-box exporter` however, I didn't find a way to get the data from the json response, any idea if it possible?

https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter

Or if there **any other tool/exporter** which can help us to check JSON response, please let me know :-)

lets assume that if the response in the json `foo=1` I need to fire alert and if `foo=2` not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Blackbox exporter

The blackbox exporter does not have a feature to validate JSON (in a sane way) but it can validate HTTP response using regex. In other words, you may try something like this:

```yaml
# blackbox exporter configuration file
# reference: https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md
  my_custom_module:
    prober: http
    http:
      valid_status_codes: []  # Defaults to 2xx
      method: GET
      # it's not necessary to use both of these
      fail_if_body_matches_regexp:
        - '.*"status":"failure".*'
      fail_if_body_not_matches_regexp:
        - '.*"status":"success".*'
```

To use this, you also have to patch your scrape job in Prometheus so that it uses `my_custom_module`, e.g.:

```yaml
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'blackbox'
    metrics_path: /probe
    params:
      module: [my_custom_module]
```

This will work well in the majority of situations but it may be not good enough to validate the full schema. In other words, it will do if your response JSON is short and simple.

## Other options

I know no alternative exporter that can do JSON validation (and I didn't bother myself looking for it) but it's not a big deal to write a custom exporter. There are client libraries for Prometheus (https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/clientlibs/) and using one of them you can easily do what you need. Here's a short example in python for you to get started:

```py
from prometheus_client import start_http_server, Gauge
from time import sleep
import requests

my_server_status = Gauge('here_goes_metric_name', 'here goes the description')

def update_status():
    response = requests.get('https://api.example.com').json()
    # check whatever you like
    if response['status'] == 'success':
        # after you scrape this, you can write an alert like "here_goes_metric_name != 1"
        my_server_status.set(1)
    else:
        my_server_status.set(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start up the server to expose the metrics.
    start_http_server(8000)
    # And update the status once in a while.
    while True:
        update_status()
        sleep(30)
    # A better way would be to write a collector class instead, 
    # but it's rather complicated for this example.
```

Comment: Thanks, assume that I need to run regex for the json output which is = `foo:1` and if not (like `foo:2` )fire alert, how should I do that with the regex for the output ?

Comment: @Jenney Do you mean how to write such regular expression? If yes, then I think this will do for `fail_if_body_not_matches_regexp`: `"foo":1[,}]` (see https://regex101.com/r/wGqTxD/1). Blackbox exporter will then give you `probe_success=1` if response does match or `probe_success=0` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and solved with telegraf.

use telegraf and expose metrics and add job to scrape metrics

config input telegraf to get data and change to metrics

```bash
[[inputs.http]]
  urls = ["some endopint"]
  interval = "1m"
  method = "GET"
  timeout = "10s"
  data_format = "json"
```

config output telegraf to expose metrics

```bash
[[outputs.prometheus_client]]
  listen = ":9274"
```

job prometheus to scrape metrics

```bash
  - job_name: endpoint_metrics
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["IP telegraf:9274"]
```

Comment: HI, thanks, what is telegraf,should I add something to the cluster ?

Comment: hi
Telegraf is a data collector and you can install it  [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/telegraf/v1.21/introduction/installation/)

no, you didn't need to add something to the Prometheus cluster.

just need to add the job to Prometheus.

Comment: But there is installation guide ...:) , we are using the kube-prom-stack , are you sure I dont need to install anything? no infulxdb? as I want to avoid it... https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack

Comment: additional question: lets assume that the API return json with value `foo:1` and if its equal `foo:1` everything is OK, and if `foo:2` we need to fire alert, how can I do that ? can you please update your answer ?

Comment: in your case, you can use AlertManager and define some rules to alert
for example, you can add a rule like this 
`response_kube_prome{foo="2"} > 0 `  then response foo: 2 is more than "1", alerting to everywhere you defined in alertmanager.yml

Comment: please accept my answer if your question is solved with my answer @Jenney